# I have a message output, I would like to have one word orange and the rest normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like the word Bournemouth to be red, but the rest of the words to inherit from the p styling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var msg;
        if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 12) msg = "Today's lunch deals in Bournemouth";
        else if (hours >= 13 && hours <= 19) msg = "Tonight's dinner deals in Bournemouth";
        else msg = "Tomorrow's lunch deals in Bournemouth";
        $('#time p').text(msg);
    });
</script>

<div id="time" style="position:absolute; width:100%; padding-top:90px; text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color:#FFF; font-size:17px;">
    <p></p> 
</div>
```

Are there certain tags I need to use for jQuery colors? I tried HTML, but this just printed out the code.

Comment: Replacing `.text()` with `.html()` will enable you to use HTML in the `msg` var. Then you'll be able to wrap specific words with a class or ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't colour something with jQuery (or at least not directly, you can modify CSS with it)

Try something like this:

```
if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 12) msg = "Today's lunch deals in <span class='red'>Bournemouth</span>";
  else if (hours >= 13 && hours <= 19) msg = "Tonight's dinner deals in <span class='red'>Bournemouth</span>";
  else msg = "Tomorrow's lunch deals in <span class='red'>Bournemouth</span>";
```

then in your html file:

```
<style>
.red {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

You also need to swap `.text(` for `.html(`

Answer (score 4):

In order to style a single line or word, you can use a `span` tag.

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="red">amet</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
.red
{
color:#FF0000;
}
```

Comment: span tag, for sure. also, inline styles are the devil.

Comment: what I was typing - although he needs to add the span to his script.

Comment: Hi, i tried that, but the text is dynamically pulled from the lines in the JQuery.

Comment: @scott - change your .text to .html with the span tags wrapped around the word.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you very much - like Mark said, i changed the .text to .html. and then used the span class round the output like you all suggested. works a treat, thank you very much!

Comment: If there are multiple places you might need this css, you probably want to change it to a class, rather than an id.

Answer (score 0):

try like below.. it will work...

Ok then use `<p>` like below..

```
msg = "Tomorrow's lunch deals in <p style='color:red'>Bournemouth</p>";
$('#time p').html(msg);
```

Comment: The font-element is highly deprecated and HTML5 doesn't support it anymore!
Use is not recommended at all!

Answer (score 0):

add span to text msg then append this as html

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var msg = " deals in <span class='highlight'>Bournemouth</span>";
  if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 12) msg = "Today's lunch"+ msg;
  else if (hours >= 13 && hours <= 19) msg = "Tonight's dinner"+ msg;
  else msg = "Tomorrow's lunch" + msg;
  $('#time p').html(msg);
});
```

add a highlight class to your css:

```
.highlight{color:red;}
```

Comment: I saw no reason to repeat the last part, so a slight refactor there.